# issue during deployement of model gcloud ml-engine versions create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

When I create a version of a machine learning model (whether it is my own model or the ML Engine census example) using the command:
$ gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 --model $MODEL_NAME --origin $MODEL_BINARIES --runtime-version 1.10

I got an error saying: ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Framework can not be identified from model path. Please make sure your model file name is correct.

Comment: what is the value of $MODEL_BINARIES? And what are the files at that location? Are you using a TF saved model?

Comment: Yes, I am using a TF saved model

Comment: What are the names of the files at the location you are sending out for deployment? Does it have saved_model.pb missing? Can you confirm that?

Comment: If you need further help, feel free to reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: am I supposed to email them or they have live chat option?

Comment: I am following this qwilabs first lab step by step 'https://google.qwiklabs.com' , at deployment I get this error

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem,JOB_ID was empty in my case, fixed by adding

JOB_ID=census_211004_181920

before OUTPUT_PATH declaration. You can check your JOB_ID in Storage Browser.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that `MODEL_BINARIES` is a folder that contains the `saved_model.pb` file.

When I followed the google documentation,

```
gsutil cp -r SavedModel/saved_model ${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/model_dir_tmp/
```

it just copied the file `saved_model.pb` into `${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/model_dir_tmp`, instead of creating `${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/model_dir_tmp/saved_model`.

Later, when I passed in `${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/model_dir_tmp/saved_model` to `--origin`, I received the complaint about Framework can not be identified from model path.

I manually went to the cloud console webpage, and created a folder `saved_model` and moved the file `saved_model.pb` into it.